# cordova/PhoneGap/ionic : fileEntry.remove(); not removing the file immediately

Tags: android, ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins, ionic-framework

fileEntry.remove(); not removing the file immediately, file persists/cached until the application is removed from the stack and restarted.Any solution of this problem?

Code I am using to remove file :

```
fileEntry.remove(function() {
                console.log('file removed successfully')
             },function(){
                console.log('error occurred')
             });
```

Comment: Did you find a solution? I've a similar problem

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it depends on in which folder you store your data or which way you get the file.

I'm saving my files in "file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/myPackageName/cache"

and i use this code to delete the files:

```
var url = "file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/myPackageName/cache/1461244585881.jpg"
window.resolveLocalFileSystemURI(url, function(file) {
        file.remove(function(){
          console.log(url + " deleted");
        },onFileSystemError);
      }, onFileSystemError);
```

All files i remove this way are deleted immediately.

Comment: I'm facing a strange problem, when implementing this.  Images are not getting removed completely. A blank thumbnail is being stored in the gallery, which are not viewable.